# Using cut for multiple variables with different types of data

Tags: r, distribution, frequency, cut

I was able to create a cumulative frequency distribution time basis and create the plot.

```
breaks = seq(as.Date('2013-01-01'),as.Date('2013-11-07'),by = 1)
dates=as.Date(Failures$Event_Date)
cum.freq=cbind.data.frame(table(cut.Date(as.Date(dates), as.Date(breaks), right=FALSE)))
result=cbind.data.frame(cum.freq,cumsum(cum.freq$Freq))
qplot(x=as.Date(Var1), y=cumsum(cum.freq$Freq), data=result,
      xlab="Date", ylab="Cumulative Failures",
      main="Frequency Distribution for failures",
      alpha=I(.5)) + scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("4 weeks"),
      labels = date_format("%m/%d"))
```

The object breaks and `cut.Date` function allows me to put all data distributed in a time interval and not only based on the sample size.  The curve and the trend line are quite different if I do not consider this.

With that restriction I need to use cut or similar function in order to add another variable named `Category` to the plot as data series and maybe use group option in `plot`.

For example:

```
Event_Date  Fault_Code  Category
06/10/13    NA  CAT1
17/05/13    10  CAT2
10/07/13    45  CAT3
11/06/13    15  CAT4
11/06/13    15  CAT4
23/08/13    16  CAT5
25/05/13    1   CAT5
28/10/13    1   CAT5
12/09/13    1   CAT5
05/06/13    NA  CAT5
05/06/13    NA  CAT5
12/06/13    NA  CAT5
21/02/13    10  CAT5
25/06/13    NA  CAT5
25/06/13    2   CAT5
17/05/13    2   CAT5
```

It is possible to use `cut` or `cut.Date` to divide the range of the sample data not only for `Event_Date` also for `Category`?

Another option would be use `dcast()` but transpose the `Category` after made `cut` in order to get all breaks.

Comment: I think you might need to go back to the `table` step an create a "Category" dimension. If you want worked examples you need to post a representative dataset, either using dput() on your data or creating one with the same overall structure using code. (The lack of such an example may be the explanation for the anonymous close vote.)

Comment: @DWin thank you for your response, I try to put an example of raw data to clarify what is my question.

Comment: You ever get this to work?